# Read sql db file from custom path in Cocos2dx of android

Tags: android, sql, database

Im a korean developer who just began `Cocos2dx`. My English is bad.

I just made a db file named `game.db` that contains several data such as item, stage, enemies etc.

But its codes to insert are too many so take too much time to build.

So I got a idea that Make db and insert all data before build, and just read them in game code, not write.

First, I made db file, and put it int `Resources/data` folder.
And in game code, function `getDBPath` returns `~~~/data/game.db`. It uses `CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils( )->fullPathForFilename( "data/game.db" )`

It works well in window environment. There is no problem. But it doesn't work in Android. It returns `assets/data/game.db` and can't open nor create db both.
Yet, i can create db when I use `CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils( )->getWritablePath( )` (and append `game.db`). Well, as you know, I cannot put db int that path directly......

Is there any difference between `fullPathForFilename` and `getWritablePath` in Android? If you know why, plz teach me about managing db in Android. Thank you.